# Neo4j finding all children of a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph model looks like this:
[Graph Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmggy.jpg)

Given a root node, I'm trying to find all the children of that root node. My query is something like:

```
MATCH(a:X{somefilter})<-[*]-(allchildren) RETURN a,allchildren;
```

`allchildren` here corresponds to `Y & Z`. 
But here I'm missing out on the Nodes & Relationships going out from Z. Like `Z-(:CHILD)->Z` I need to capture those nodes too.

How can I capture all the children nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are not just after the children but the children's children as well.

This will return all of the paths (an object that contains both nodes and relationships) emanating from your root node down two levels.  So, in your picture, it would stop traversing at the children of Y and Z. Scoping the relationship type to MEMBER and CHILD will ensure the path only includes those types of relationships.

```
MATCH p=(a:X {somefilter})-[:MEMBER|CHILD*0..2]-(allchildren) 
RETURN p
```

In your picture it appears at though `Z` is in fact a child of itself an `Y`. It does not appear to have any other children.

If you query from the root node  *X* without direction to can capture relationships and nodes that are outbound from `Z` as well as opposed to just the ones that are inbound.

Comment: This still doesn't capture the relationships emanating from Z->Z :(

Comment: what happens if you remove the directedness off of the relationship?

Comment: We're talking about 50k nodes and 6 million edges. Undirected link runs forever.